# add your own custom route to devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

i've seen a bunch of posts on how to rename already-declared routes in devise. I want to expand devise to have my own route check for and idle session.  I am implementing a simple js check every 1 minute that I want to hit 'check_active' in the devise sessions controller.  I tried this but no luck:

```
devise_scope :sessions do
    get 'check_active'
end
```

Is there way to *expand* devise with a custom route (not rename an already-existing one) ?

UPDATE - almost there, i did this

```
# already had this in routes

devise_for :users, :controllers =>
    { registrations: 'registrations',
    confirmations: 'confirmations',
    sessions: 'sessions',
    passwords: 'passwords',
    omniauth_callbacks: "omniauth_callbacks"}

# added this

devise_scope :sessions do
    get '/check_active' => 'sessions#check_active'
end
```

I have a js firing, i have it get '/check_active' as rake routes shows this:

```
check_active GET      /check_active(.:format)
```

But when it fires, the controller 404s with

AbstractController::ActionNotFound (Could not find devise mapping for path "/check_active".
    This may happen for two reasons:

```
1) You forgot to wrap your route inside the scope block. For example:                                                                                        

  devise_scope :user do                                                                                                                                      
    get "/some/route" => "some_devise_controller"                                                                                                            
  end                                                                                                                                                        

2) You are testing a Devise controller bypassing the router.                                                                                                 
   If so, you can explicitly tell Devise which mapping to use:                                                                                               

   @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]

):
```

Comment: you created the check_active method in sessions_controller right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are overwriting Devise's default controllers, it is not any different from any other controller to add your own route.

After you [create your devise controllers](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/Tool:-Generate-and-customize-controllers) to overwrite, do the following:

Under sessions_controller declare a method

```
# app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb
def check_active
   # do what you want to do
end
```

And in your router:

```
# config/routes.rb
devise_scope :sessions do
    get 'check_active', to: "devise/sessions#check_active"
end
```

Comment: thanks                       filler filller filler filer

Comment: actually i thought this was working, i get `AbstractController::ActionNotFound (The action 'check_active' could not be found for Devise::SessionsController)`

Comment: even though rake routes shows `rake routes|grep check_active
                                                              check_active GET      /check_active(.:format)`

Comment: my mistake, i don't use devise/ i have a root controller, thanks again

Comment: updating question for details on needed help

Comment: check my answer for a better way to do this

Answer (score 1):

I was trying the same thing and realized that the scope should be for `user` and not `sessions`, also ensure that it has to be singular.

```
devise_scope :user do
    get '/check_active' => 'sessions#check_active'
end
```

**Edit:** Adding [link](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/ActionDispatch%2FRouting%2FMapper%3Adevise_scope) to help docs for better understanding